# Trailing backslash error web-mode content type

Tags: debugging, emacs

I get this error when trying to set content type in web-mode: `File mode specification error: (invalid-regexp Trailing backslash)`

I have had a hard time debugging this. I'm very new to emacs so I need some help setting web-mode. I have been following the documentation in web-mode.org but it has been difficult to decypher. Thanks.

```el
(use-package
 web-mode
 :defer 2
 :ensure t
 :mode ("\\.html?\\"
        "\\.hbs$\\"
        "\\.vue$\\"
        "\\.css?\\"
        "components/.*\\.js[x]?\\'"
        "containers/.*\\.js[x]?\\'")
 :config (progn
           (setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing t
                 web-mode-enable-auto-opening t
                 web-mode-enable-auto-pairing t
                 web-mode-enable-auto-indentation t
                 web-mode-enable-auto-quoting t
                 ;; right now paired with AutoComplete
                 web-mode-ac-sources-alist
                 '(("css" . (ac-source-css-property))
                   ("vue" . (ac-source-words-in-buffer ac-source-abbrev))
                   ("html" . (ac-source-words-in-buffer ac-source-abbrev)))
                 web-mode-content-types-alist
                 '(("jsx" . "components/.*\\.js[x]?\\'")
                   ("jsx" . "containers/.*\\.js[x]?\\'")))))

;; usually I set them in containers/ or components/ directorie
;; and to keep seperate from plain JS

;; adjust indents for web-mode to 2 spaces
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode. Adjust indents"
  ;;; http://web-mode.org/
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

Comment: What does "when trying to set content type in web-mode" mean?  What is the process for reproducing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list of regexps after `:mode`, make sure that they all end with `\\'`.  Currently two of them do, but four of them lost the final `'` character.

```
 :mode ("\\.html?\\'"
        "\\.hbs$\\'"
        "\\.vue$\\'"
        "\\.css?\\'"
        "components/.*\\.js[x]?\\'"
        "containers/.*\\.js[x]?\\'")
```

`\'` is a special regexp construct that "matches the empty string, but only at the end of the buffer or string being matched against".

Comment: thanks !!! that worked. Btw, it was very late when I wrote the post. What I meant to say is that I was trying to set web mode according to content types. for example, if you are working with React. This setup works nicely, given that you have AutoComplete installed as well.